# Maven Plugin dependencies included in MANIFEST.MF

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to build a jar with a valid Classpath in its MANIFEST.MF within Eclipse-IDE(Version Kepler Service Release 2; Maven 3.0.4) . The relevant configuration for the maven-jar-plugin in my pom.xml is

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
      <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
        <classpathLayoutType>custom</classpathLayoutType>
        <customClasspathLayout>$${artifact.artifactId}-$${artifact.version}.$${artifact.extension}</customClasspathLayout>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However this does not work as expected. For example I'm using the findbugs-maven-plugin and this plugin creates some Maven-Dependencies, namely the findbugs-maven-plugin-2.5.4.jar in my local repository. Heres the configuration for the findbugs-plugin

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <findbugsXmlOutput>true</findbugsXmlOutput>
    <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
    <!-- Optional directory to put findbugs xdoc xml report -->
    <xmlOutputDirectory>target/findbugs</xmlOutputDirectory>
  </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

This is ok, but this dependency also makes it in the classpath-entry of my MANIFEST.MF which looks like this (excerpt):

```
lib/findbugs-maven-plugin-2.5.4.jar
```

The problem is, I have no clue how to disable this behaviour.

What I have tried so far:
Use the maven-dependency-plugin and define excludeGroupId and excludeArtifactId entries, which solved another problem, where the dependencies where all copied to lib-Folder in target-Directory.

Clearly I am missing something here.

Comment: AFAIK classpath entries on the MANIFEST should only be relevant to your project runtime dependencies. Unless you have put findbugs somewhere as a dependency of your project, it shouldn't be there in your JAR MANIFEST. Maybe check with a mvn dependency:tree to see where this dependency comes from.

Comment: Great tip which showed me that the dependency indeed comes from another jar. Is there a way to get rid of the transitive dependency in my MANIFEST.MF without changing the pom it comes from?

Comment: There are two ways: First, when declaring the dep which gives you the unwanted JAR, you can exclude that JAR, see here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html "How to use dependency exclusions". Or you can also re-declare and set a provided scope for that unwanted JAR. In both ways, this will remove if from being packaged and present in the MANIFEST. But if that other JAR needs it at runtime, you'll get some ClassNotFoundExceptions

Comment: Seems like we both have an answer for this question :). Mine covers your first approach. Perhaps you post your second approach as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: Well not sure the question itself is answered, as the base problem comes from something else that the Archiver setting your plugins inside the MANIFEST classpath. And in the end, the library that depends directly on the plugin is more than suspect, especially if you need to remove it later...

Comment: For me it is answered, because it is possible to solve the problem explained. How that dependency was aquired in this library should be another question. But you are right that it is suspect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I managed to solve this problem.

The dependency came from an module base I was working on and which. It defined the dependency to the findbugs-maven-plugin-2.5.4.jar. This dependency was recognized by maven and placed in the classpath of my jar I wanted to build.

The solution to this problem can be found here http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html. It is possible to define excludes to transitive libraries. The dependency to base ind my module must therefore be written as:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>base</groupId>
  <artifactId>base</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Thanks to Tome who finally pointed me in the right direction!